# How to return total to <td> tag angular JS from controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to return a total IR for each table cell. This is not working And I am not sure why. How

```
 $scope.getTotalb = function () {
        var totalb = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
            if (120 > $scope.items[i].product && $scope.items[i].product> 90) {
                var product = $scope.items[i].IR;
                totalb += ($scope.items[i].IR);
            }
            return totalb;
        }
    }
    $scope.getTotalc = function () {
        var totalc = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
            if (90 > $scope.items[i].product&& $scope.items[i].product> 60) {
                var product = $scope.items[i].IR;
                totalc += ($scope.items[i].IR);
            }
            return totalc;
        }
    }
```

For Each table data cell, call the function to get total.

```
<td><b>Total:</b></td>
            <td><b>{{Totala()}}</b></td>
            <td><b></b>{{Totalb()}}</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your code.

First, you should put the `return` statement at the end of your function instead of within your `for` loop.

Second, the names of the functions are different in your template. In your controller you use `getTotalb` but in the template you use `Totalb`.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your return statement outside of for loop

Comment: That hasnt made a difference

Answer (score 0):

remove the "return ...." from your 2 "for" loops and make your totals available through the scope.

```
$scope.getTotalb = function () {
    var totalb = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
        if (120 > $scope.items[i].product && $scope.items[i].product> 90) {
            var product = $scope.items[i].IR;
            totalb += ($scope.items[i].IR);
        }

    }
     $scope.totalb=totalb ;

}
$scope.getTotalc = function () {
    var totalc = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
        if (90 > $scope.items[i].product&& $scope.items[i].product> 60) {
            var product = $scope.items[i].IR;
            totalc += ($scope.items[i].IR);
        }

    }
    $scope.totalc=totalc ;
}
```